# How to apply ultraThinMaterial, but without light tint / fill?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am working on an effect that should essentially blur contents behind the view and and `.ultraThinMaterial` achieves exactly that. However in addition to bluring content in the background it adds light / white tint or fill as well. i.e [attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJVB0m.jpg) has content placed against very dark background, but applying `.ultraThinMaterial` on top makes everything lighter.

My current implementation looks like this, The darkest I could possibly get is by explicitly setting environment color-scheme to light. I tried playing with blend modes, but applying them removes the blur. Is there a way to get a blur effect, without this light tint?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ModalLayoutBackdrop: View {
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      content
      VStack {}
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .environment(\.colorScheme, .light)
        .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: How about `.blur(radius: 10)`?

Comment: I think that needs to be applied to the content correct? I tried doing that but it leads to weird appearance along the edges of the screen because content kind of "shrinks in" the more blur you apply to it, adding scaling effect is an option to mitigate this, but ideally I'm looking for a solution that wouldn't require this.

Comment: Well then I think you need to write your own Metal shader. This is just how materials behave.

Comment: What you can do is apply a semi-transparent dark layer to compensate for the material effect. See part 2 of the answer to [SwiftUI Visual Blur Effect with clear background](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77290873/20386264) for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve a blur effect without the light tint:

Custom Blur View Using UIVisualEffectView: Instead of relying on .ultraThinMaterial, you can create a custom SwiftUI view that wraps a UIVisualEffectView from UIKit, which allows for more control over the blur effect. This approach enables you to use a UIBlurEffect with a style that suits your needs, potentially avoiding the additional tint.
swift

```
struct BlurView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var style: UIBlurEffect.Style = .dark

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIVisualEffectView {
        return UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: style))
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIVisualEffectView, context: Context) {
        uiView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: style)
    }
}
```

Then, in your SwiftUI view:

```
struct ModalLayoutBackdrop: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            content
            VStack {}
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(BlurView(style: .dark))
        }
    }
}
```